# Running update on selected array records

Tags: php, sql, db2

I have a working test script which is doing something pretty straightforward:

Getting an order_id from one table and selecting all data for it from another table based on that order_id.

This works but I'm a little lost on the best way to go about something else at the end of this.

Whether my query in `$getOrderNumbers` returns one or multiple records, and the following script within the while loop will execute either one or multiple records, upon each successful execution for the `$getOrderDetails` I want to update the other feilds of my `STATUS` Table for the originally selected records.

So this is the working script:

```
$getOrderNumbers = "
    SELECT 
        ORDER_ID
    FROM STATUS
    WHERE ORDER_STATUS = 'S'
    AND IS_ACTIVE = 0
";

try {
    $getNumbers = $DB2conn->prepare($getOrderNumbers);
    $ORDNumbers = $getNumbers->execute();
}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

while ($row2 = $getNumbers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $orderNumParams = [
        ":ORDER_ID" => $row2["ORDER_ID"],
    ];

    print_r($row2);

    $getOrderDetails = "
        SELECT *
        FROM tableOne
        WHERE  invoice  = :ORDER_ID
    ";

    try {
        $orderDetailCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($getOrderDetails);
        $detailRslt = $orderDetailCheck->execute($orderNumParams);
        $orderDetailCount = $orderDetailCheck->fetch();
        print_r($orderDetailCount);
    }catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Basically, when that's successful in querying tableOne for each record I want to run an  update on STATUS like so:

```
UPDATE STATUS
SET IS_ACTIVE = 1
AND DATE_UPDATED = CURRENT_DATE;
```

How can I make it so that upon each successful completion I can then set my original table and record by this update?

So if my first query gets ORDER_ID 123456, then when my 2nd query is successful I would essentially run:

```
UPDATE STATUS
SET IS_ACTIVE = 1
AND DATE_UPDATED = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE ORDER_ID = 123456;
```

Comment: Why not just join the queries instead of doing multiple queries?

Comment: I would but I have some other working logic within the loop that I've omitted from here. I'm trying to base several operations on the orders (ORDER_ID) in the initial array if possible

Comment: It also involves different databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare another statement to do the updates.

```
$update = $DB2conn->prepare("
    UPDATE STATUS
    SET ACTIVE = 1, DATE_UPDATED = CURRENT_DATE
    WHERE ORDER_ID = :ORDER_ID");
```

Notice that columns to update are separated by with comma, not `AND`.

Then inside the loop you can do:

```
$update->execute($orderNumParams);
```

BTW, you don't need to call `$DB2conn->prepare($getOrderDetails);` every time through the loop. You only need to prepare the statement once, then execute it in the loop.

Comment: That worked, much more straightforward than I thought. Thank you!